# HQL editor for eclipse juno with annotation based hibernate

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, hibernate, hql

I am using Hibernate 3.6 with eclipse juno. Is there any plug in available for running HQL queries , just like we use SQL clients for native SQL queries?

We are  **not using .hbn.cfg but annotations and JPA's entityManager**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the HQL Query Builder as a part of the Hibernate Tools from JBoss

[Hibernate Tools from JBoss http://iablog.sybase.com/paulley/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/hql_editor_view.PNG](http://iablog.sybase.com/paulley/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/hql_editor_view.PNG)